# I'm new to Laravel, I want to save my logs and errors in database cause I need to display it on a page.

Tags: laravel-5.4, laravel-5.5, bugsnag

I'm new to Laravel 5.5, I want to save my logs and errors in database cause I need to display it on a page please someone help me to achieve this without using bugsnag. Thank you!

Comment: use log reader package to display log contents from file into a page. https://github.com/stevebauman/log-reader

Comment: thanks @Tushar I will try this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this package "rap2hpoutre/laravel-log-viewer" and it allows me to display the logs, saving the logs in a database don't need.